# More control over updating UITableView and UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to implement expanding `UITableViewCells` where I have complete control over the animation of the transition from collapsed to expanded and back.
I have an array, `cellDataList`, that holds the state of my `UITableViewCells`, i.e. `height`, `color`, `data`, `isExpanded` etc.

I implement:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath == selectedIndex)
        return expandedHeight;
    return collapsedHeight; 

}
```

and I implement:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /*
    some logic that tests if the indexPath is already selected,
    which will collapse the cell, if a previous cell needs to be collapsed before the 
    new expands etc.
    */

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

My cell is a custom `UITableViewCell` where I build my content in `drawRect:`
The cell has a `UIView` (background) that serves as a custom background for the cell, this view I would like to
animate from collapsed to expanded and back, not just setFrame in one 'jump', as it does now.

I can't really figure out where to 'intercept' the tableView updater chain, to achieve this.

When I do the `[tableView beginUpdates] - [tableView endUpdates]` above, it starts to get a bit obscure what happens.
I assume

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called to update the cells
at the indexes specified. This in turn will ask `heightForCellAtIndexPath` which height to set the cell. If I set a breakpoint in my custom cells `setFrame:` method
I can see the caller is

```
[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] ().
```

This sets the new frame for the cell, then I assume `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` is called somehow so the cell can render for the frame provided.
The `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` will eventually call my custom `drawRect:` and render the content of the cell. This works as expected, but I can't figure
out where and how I will animate the frame for my background, also in a way so it is only done when clicked and not every time `setFrame:` is called (during scrolling etc). 
When I do the above the tableView animates to make room for the new cell size, it is
this animation I would like to 'mimic' with the background view on my cell.

I see this effect in apps like Tweetbot and path but I can't seem to replicate it.

Hope some one can help me in the right direction, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure that i understood your question exactly:) But you can use Key Value Observer (KVO) to check when you need to play your animation then call your table reload method.

```
- (void)reloadTable
{

if (self.isViewLoaded) {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

}

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
[self reloadTable]; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the really short version is "is there a way to animate a uitableviewcells height on tap so it is in sync with the uitableviews animation where it moves aside to make room for a new size cell". Where does the code you provided go? Controller, customcell or tableview?

Comment: You should change the height of your cell in tableView dynamically but after that you need to reload your table. Try to debug your code to check if it comes to your new height value. But you write your custom cell once do not change this. In your controller part, access the your custom cell and change its height then reload the table.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to add a dummy cell below the cell that was tapped. I explain this thorougly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952691/how-to-create-tweetbots-popup-in-uitableviewcell/7290977#7290977).

Basically:

1. Keep track of what cells are been tapped in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and update it appropriately. Which one needs to be deleted? Where will the new dummy cell be next?
2. Return the correct account whenever the dummy cell is present.
3. Account for the fact that the dummy cell is not part of your model. Offset the `indexPath`.