# In iOS, what's the best way to implement sliding "drawers"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I'm not sure if "drawer" is the right term, but I'm wanting to find out how to implement  dialogs that slide out from under an element and push the other content on the view down.

Good examples are Apple's Weather app, which reveals detailed forecast info when a day is clicked, and Tapbots' Tweetbot, which [reveals Tweet-level controls](http://tapbots.com/img/software/tweetbot/screenshot_02_large.jpg) when a tweet is clicked.

Thanks for any info!

Comment: [This might may be of some interest for you](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/SideSwipeTableView) and [this one also](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/04/14/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-side-swiping-on-a-table/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7290977/639668). I've used it and it works perfectly. Basically what you're doing is adding a new row to the table view when the user taps on a row.

Answer (score 4):

One option:

Create a view for the "drawer". You can place it behind another view, or just off screen. When the user taps in the right spot or otherwise causes the drawer to "open," move the view to it's "open" position. If the drawer is opening vertically with respect to the screen, you'll probably want to slide the it up or down by the height of the drawer; if it's opening horizontally, slide it left or right by one drawer width. Use Core Animation to make it easy to animate the change in position and make it look like the drawer is sliding open. The `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` animation curve will make this look nice. Obviously, move the drawer in the other direction to close again.